# Completely remove Ubuntu from Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bios, uninstall, bootloader

I have the following situation:

I have a PC with Win10 installed. My computer has 2 SSD disks, one with Windows installation and the other was completely empty, so, I decided to install Ubuntu 18  in it.

I booted from a USB with Ubuntu installer. The default option in the wizard was to install in the same disk as windows, so I chose the "do something else" option. I selected the empty disk, created the mount points:
 /, /home and swap

The installation finished fine and asked me to reboot. When I rebooted, a menu with purple background showed me the Windows and Ubuntu options. I chose Win in that very first reboot to make sure everything remained fine in that OS, and it did.

Then, I decided to restart in order to validate my Ubuntu installation, but BIOS just hung and it didn't even recognize my keyboard. No matter how many times I rebooted, I couldn't get past the Bios logo screen but not being able to access BIOS setting or do anything else but turn off.

I had to do a CMOS reset. After that, I booted with only the Windows 10 disk connected to the PC just to make sure everything ran smoothly. It did.

Then, I decided to reboot my computer, just to make sure. But, it happended just the same: BIOS hangs, no keyboard detection and doesn't get past that start up BIOS screen.

I did a second CMOS reset with only the Win 10 hard disk connected (again), but accessed the BIOS settings and in the Boot Options I see Windows, UEFI, the name of my SSD disk, and an Ubuntu option. Remember, the disk where I installed Ubuntu is not even connected. I don't understand how Ubuntu appears as a possible candidate for booting sequence if the disk where I installed is not even connected!!!!

How can I get rid of the Ubuntu traces that appear in my disk when choosing the Boot sequence in the BIOS? I am afraid (just guessing) that's the reason everytime I do a CMOS reset to BIOS, it only allows one boot. When I boot for the second time, my BIOS just hangs and I have to CMOS reset again and again.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: UEFI Boot options are stored in NVRAM. You need to use an editor to manage them. Also, consider updating the firmware because it is obviously buggy.

Comment: **Re the hanging UEFI (not BIOS)** I noted SSD drives can be read by Linux with the [AHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) standard only, while Win10 recognizes a drive both with AHCI and a [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID)-related standard. These are options of the **boot loader** under the [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA)-headings. If you had a RAID-like settings, no way the boot loader made you splash into Ubuntu. To test this, you could change the boot loader settings into AHCI and try if you can open both doors with that one key.

Comment: **Re the ubuntu traces in the boot menu**, this is because GRUB the Ubuntu loader lives on the EFI partition; even if you wipe Ubuntu from the OS partition, and if that boot loader is on top of the priority list, you will splash into it, although it will ask you what to do, justly. I asked a question about removing this even before installing Win10 here https://superuser.com/q/1535620

Answer (score 1):

Try following these steps...

**Deleting Linux (Ubuntu) partition in Windows**

You may skip this step since you have installed Ubuntu on a separate drive (SSD). However, if some partition (such as SWAP, Boot, etc) are installed in the main hard drive, you may have to do this.

Log into Windows and start **Windows disk management tool**. You can do this by searching “`diskmgmt.msc`”.

[image: Start DiskMgmnt]

Identify the Linux partition(s) and delete those partitions. These deleted partitions will be available as a chunk of free space. You can either extend the existing partition or create a new Windows partition out of it.

Note: Usually Linux partition(s) have no label under the File System column while Windows partitions will be identified by either NTFS or FAT. However, there might be a one or two partition that belongs to Windows but still have no label under the File System column.
Example: Healthy EFI System Partition (100MB)

[image: Disk Partitions]

**Fixing Windows boot loader**

Linux has been removed from your computer, but its boot loader persists.
To remove this, you need a Windows installer disc or Windows repair disc.

*How to Create and Use a Recovery Drive or System Repair Disc 10: https://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/*

Insert the Windows installer or recovery disc into your computer, restart your computer, and let it boot from that disc. 
After booting from your disc, click the “Repair your computer” option on the main install screen.

[image: Main install screen]
<sup>Image Source: https://www.howtogeek.com</sup>

On the “Choose an option” screen, click the “Troubleshoot” option and then on the “Advanced options” screen, click the “Command Prompt” option.

[image: Choose an option screen]
<sup>Image Source: https://www.howtogeek.com</sup>

[image: Advanced options screen]
<sup>Image Source: https://www.howtogeek.com</sup>

At the Command Prompt, type the following command and then press Enter to fix the Windows boot loader.

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Once it’s done, restart your computer and this time windows should boot normally.
However, If this not work, you can also try the “Automatic Repair” option On the “Advanced options” screen.

---

**Updated ...**
If you're still seeing the Ubuntu boot option in the **Windows Boot Manager**, try following steps.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on your keyboard to open the Run dialog box, and enter `msconfig` to open the System Configuration tool. 
Go to the Boot tab and delete unwanted boot options.

[image: System Configuration tool]

---

<sup>***References and resources***</sup>
<sup>• [How to Remove Linux (Ubuntu) From Dual Boot in Windows 10 []](https://youtu.be/5Rq4zovHiWk)</sup>
<sup>• [How to Uninstall Windows or Linux After Dual-Booting](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-or-linux-after-dual-booting-508710422)</sup>
<sup>• [How to use the Command Prompt to fix issues with your PC's boot records](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-fix-issues-your-boot-records)</sup>
<sup>• [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/539976)</sup>
<sup>• [How to Uninstall a Linux Dual-Boot System From Your Computer](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)</sup>
<sup>• [How To Uninstall Ubuntu From Windows Dual Boot Safely](https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/)</sup>
<sup>• [How to Delete Old Boot Menu Options on Windows 10](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/delete-boot-menu-options-windows/)</sup>

Comment: It worked. However, I'm still seeing the "Ubuntu" option in the boot sequence screen in the BIOS.

Comment: Press `Win` + `R` on your keyboard to open the Run dialog box, and enter `msconfig` to open **System Configuration** tool. Go to the **Boot** tab and delete unwanted boot options.  
More info: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/delete-boot-menu-options-windows/

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problem- tried many fixes, including yours.  Gave up.  Am now buying new computer and hoping to salvage my personal data.
Oh, and will avoid Linux forever.  No offence but unless one is an expert, it's a nightmare

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment, please don’t post comments as answers. At one point or another you will earn reputation and privileges on this site, and if your answer is downvoted, you will lose those again. 
When you earned enough reputation, you will be able to post comments to the original question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1092837)