# Intentionally and safely delete Ubuntu directory in EFI partition with Live Ubuntu USB

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, uefi, efi, clean-install

#### Situation

I want to clean a computer to a near-pristine state with **Windows 10** after having tried **Ubuntu 18.04** on it. I have all the overall procedure under the belt.

The last detail is that the **boot loader** still sees an ubuntu entry. 
This is because there is a legacy EFI/ubuntu **directory** in the EFI **partition**.
I would like to clean that too.

#### Windows installer, and expectation

When reinstalling Windows I don't want go as far as making a new user profile though.

I understand from the discussion in [Completely remove Ubuntu from Windows 10 PC](https://superuser.com/q/1410681/491642) that, even when you proceed with the repair mode in **Windows installer**, that that EFI directory will survive. 
To remove it you need to act from a user profile using dedicated commands.
This is another guided tour I bumped in: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/delete-boot-menu-options-windows/
My first option is to avoid this avenue.

#### Ubuntu installer, and questions

Likewise, before reinstalling Windows 10, I can use the Ubuntu Live USB to mount and manipulate the EFI partition.
Simply `sudo rm -rf EFI/ubuntu` from the terminal would clean that **directory** (repeat: not partition).

The questions are:

- Is that safe and in which way it is not?
- Are there, for example, other files in the EFI partition keeping the books of the contents and potentially throwing exceptions down the line? There is another directory `EFI/BOOT`, for example, containing BOOTX64.EFI and fbx64.efi.

  Or would the boot loader and the future Windows 10 splash into and roam around `EFI/windows`, insouciant of what its siblings are/were?
- If this perhaps safer using a better command than `rm ...`?

#### Do-nothing versus Do-nothing-harmful

I am aware that keeping `EFI/ubuntu` is no harm.
I would know whether removing it is just as much so, and opt accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan is sound, but please make a backup of this partition first. I'd recommend Clonezilla because of its ease of use.

> Is that safe and in which way it is not?

It is safe.

> Are there, for example, other files in the EFI partition [...]?

Yes. The `EFI/BOOT` directory gets special treatment from UEFI - `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` wil boot by default if no other loaders are configured in UEFI. Both Windows 10 and Ubuntu will drop its files into `EFI/BOOT`. I'm not sure which set you do currently have, but removing `EFI/BOOT` entirely should be safe.

If you don't find this method elegant, you can format the partition to FAT32 and recreate it using Windows 10 installation media (Microsoft offers free downloads for those). On the first screen press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open command prompt, then assign a letter to EFI partition and recreate boot files:

1. Run `diskpart`:

   - `list disk`
   - `select disk 0` (or other number listed by previous command, but usually it's 0)
   - `list partition`
   - `select partition 1` (or other number listed by previous command - EFI partition will have type "System").
   - `assign letter=a`

   EFI partition will be mounted as A:.

   - `exit`
2. Recreate boot files:

   `bcdboot X:\windows /s A:` (installation media is always mounted as X:)

> If this perhaps safer using a better command than `rm ...`?

`rm` is fine. The nice thing about UEFI is that it uses regular FAT filesystem with regular files - nothing exotic, no hidden sectors etc.

---

Resources I've used:

- [This forum thread](https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/52837-moving-recreating-efi-partition.html)
- [bcdboot docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di)

Comment: EFI/BOOT contains BOOTX64.EFI and fbx64.efi only. I checked that they relate to Microsoft with `strings [filename] | grep -i microsoft` and left them alone --- I have then removed the EFI/ubuntu directory; at the new reboot, it disappeared from the boot list as intended. It worked. Thanks for sparring